# Want discord bot users to be able to specify specific default arguments

Tags: python, arguments, discord

im making a discord bot through python
for simplicity's sake:

```
@client.command()
async def number(ctx, country_code="+90", phone_number=None):
       pass
```

when people in my server want to use this command, i want them to be able to specify the second argument, without having to specify the first. how would i go about doing that? thanks in advance

Comment: In this case, you can do a method overload with the params you want, in this case: async def number(country_code="+90", phone_number=None):

Comment: sorry, wanted to rephrase my question. i want the suers to be able to specify the phone_number, without having to specify the country code. through discord. is that possible?